# Kubernetes liveness probe restarted container keeps failing to access some resources

Tags: kubernetes, livenessprobe

There are **kubernetes** microservices (written in .net core 3.1) having liveness probe. When this liveness probe detects some other external resources (e.g. redis, rabbitmq) not accessible, kubernetes restarts the container of the services. The restart mechanism works as expected.

The **problem** is that after kube restarted the service container, the service still cannot connect to the resource. It seems that connection issues cannot be fixed with kube liveness restart.
The only solution (workaround) in this situation is the service **re-deployment**. If the particular service is re-deployed, the connection problem will stop right away.

**What is the difference between a service deployment and liveness probe restart that makes the connection work again in case of deployment?**

Comment: There should be no difference. My guess is that the problem is with the service itself but since I have no knowledge about the service/deployment, that will just stay my guess.

Comment: "When this liveness probe detects some other external resources (e.g. redis, rabbitmq) not accessible[...]. after kube restarted the service container, the service still cannot connect to the resource" - Have you considered that maybe the problem is not with the service but with external resporces (e.g. redis). Restating service in this case won't help.

Comment: "The only solution in this situation is the service re-deployment" - do you also redeploy "some other external resources", or only the .net servce?

Comment: Only .net services have been redeployed.  External resources remained intact.